# Dynamic linq syntax for subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I want to have the following query in Dynamic LINQ.. I have tried some solutions but have not succeeded yet.

```
 select
    SUM([Value1]) AS [Sum]
        ,[Dim1] AS [Primary], 
        [Dim2] AS [Secondary]
    from
    (
        SELECT 
          value1, dim1, dim2
        FROM [BudgetLine]
        WHERE [BudgetID] = 4
    ) as a
    GROUP BY [Dim1], [Dim2]
```

My current code looks like this, but I need to rewrite it to give me the SQL above.

```
    var query = (DatabaseConnection.DataMemoryContext.GetTable<BudgetLineEntity>().AsQueryable()
    .Where(String.Format("BudgetID={0}",filter.BudgetId))
    .GroupBy(String.Format("new({0},{1})",primaryDimension.Name,secondaryDimension.Name), "new(Value1)")
    .Select(String.Format("new (Key.{0} as Primary, Key.{1} as Secondary, Sum(Value1) as Sum)",primaryDimension.Name,secondaryDimension.Name)));
```

primaryDimension.Name and SecondaryDimension.Name contain the name of the columns to group by.

Comment: You will never get that exact code, LINQ will use extents and lot of aliases, etc, so getting that exact code is as far I know impossible

Comment: ok, can I get something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider querying the database on your subquery, then stashing the result in a datatable which you can then compute off of.

```
SELECT 
value1, dim1, dim2
FROM [BudgetLine]
WHERE [BudgetID] = 4
```

[MSDN article - Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing that (saving the result of the query you mentioned in a database table and running Dynamic LINQ on that) . It resulted in a query execution time improvement of about 20% so I'm content.