# SQL Server CE performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-ce, in-memory-database

I am interested in an in-memory database with high performance. I know several, like eXtremeDB, SQLite, Hana, TimesTen etc.

Now Microsoft is offering SQL Server CE not only for mobile device, and it's free (nice!). I was wondering about it's performance. It's nice that it supports LINQ and all, but I really need performance, say, over 50K inserts per second (which most in-memory DBs account for)

Does anyone know of a benchmark, or can share their own experience about it's performance, I'd appreciate some insight.

Thanks, 
Shade

Comment: I have an Insert library and some performance figures here: https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/ - 178.000 rows/second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this previous answer for the question:
"SQL Server CE 4.0 performance comparison"

They asked a comparison between CE and 
•SQLite 
•SQL Server (1) 
•SQL Server Express *
•maybe Firebird

[SQL Server CE 4.0 performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249240/sql-server-ce-4-0-performance-comparison)

BY THE WAY, there was no release of version for three years now, that means probably that MS is dropping support for SQL CE, (a pitty if you ask me).

Regards, 
M

Comment: thanks. most of all for the tip on MS not supporting it anymore.